# change event of select in Angular 2 not working in Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, microsoft-edge

this is my code:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" (change)="changeTower()" [(ngModel)]="_selectedTower._id">
    <option attr.value="{{tower._id}}" *ngFor="#tower of _towers;">Tower {{tower.name}}</option>
</select>
```

1. In firefox `changeTower()` is not hitting at all.
2. In Edge it works only for first time and then stop working at all.

.

value of _selectedTower._id is not getting changed after first change..

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox https://plnkr.co/edit/0aKi1C966h80CPVHR169?p=preview and edge

Comment: yes its working fine in this plunk r, but not in my code, don't know what's wrong

Comment: Do you use the latest Angular version? Do you use `*.min.js` instead of `*.dev.js` (`*.min.js` is still broken AFAIK)?

Comment: found the issue, I update your plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/Z0yi2S3JGQ7nNMFeeOHT?p=preview

value of model is not getting changed

Answer (score 2):

That is a known issue in Firefox and Edge

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6573
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6703

The workaround is to use the `(change)` event (and the events value) instead of `ngModelChange`

```
<select [ngModel]="value" (change)="changeValue($event.target.value)">
```

AFAIK there are already fixes but not yet released.

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8148
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7185